# Will dropping AUTO_INCREMENT rebuild table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, blocking

I've got table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblsomething` (
  `something_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   …
 PRIMARY KEY (`something_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=144620955
```

I need to drop the auto increment. So I'm thinking to do:

```
ALTER TABLE tblsomething MODIFY something_id int NOT NULL;
```

But this part of MySQL doc worries me:

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE works by
>   making a temporary copy of the
>   original table. The alteration is
>   performed on the copy, and then the
>   original table is deleted and the new
>   one is renamed. While ALTER TABLE is
>   executing, the original table is
>   readable by other sessions. Updates
>   and writes to the table are stalled
>   until the new table is ready, and then
>   are automatically redirected to the
>   new table without any failed updates.

So is dropping auto increment actually one of these cases? Will it lock up my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing (or setting) AUTO_INCREMENT flag does not rebuild the entire table. You can easily test that using a table with a large number of rows (setting that flag is almost instantaneous).

**Update:** This was probably true long time ago (with MyISAM), but looks it is no longer the case.

Comment: I kind of suspected that. Is it officially documented anywhere?

Comment: Actually it isn't true. Removing auto_increment for big tables takes very long time to acomplish. Been there several times.

Comment: This is simply false. Either elaborate on how to set the flag or show a real example of how to modify a column without rewriting the table.

Comment: It took longer to remove AUTO_INCREMENT than it did to insert 8 million records. It has to be recreating the table, which is sad. I'm running away, as fast as I can, back to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Certain `ALTER TABLE` statements will always produce a dreaded rebuild as your describe.

In the event of removing `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields the only way to prevent this is some unsupported hackery. This involves modifying a copy of the table's `.frm` file. It works because schema information is held separately from the data and index information and the modifications don't produce any inconsistencies between the three.

You can find a discussion about it at [mysqlperformanceblog.org](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/29/hacking-to-make-alter-table-online-for-certain-changes/) and in the [High Performance MySQL book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&lpg=PA146&dq=modifying%20.frm&pg=PA146#v=onepage&q=modifying%20.frm&f=false). It's important to stress that it is unsupported though. I'd recommend that you test both methods (plain `ALTER TABLE` and `.frm` editing) on a copy of the data first. See how long both processes take and check the consistency after.

---

Edit: Sorry, I re-read what was written and `ALTER COLUMN` doesn't apply to what you're doing.  I've updated the text above.

Comment: So actually I should do "ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN .. DROP DEFAULT" rather than modify?